# Cloud Endpoints Cookies Authentication Custom Domain

Tags: python, ajax, google-app-engine, xmlhttprequest, google-cloud-endpoints

Alright. I am aware with the limitation that Endpoints can't be served on a custom domain. However, I am serving my application on the custom domain and calling the endpoints with the *.appspot.com domain.

The whole app used to work being served from appspot, but now that my app on custom domain is calling the endpoints on appspot authentication cookies (which what I am using btw) stopped being sent with the XHR calls.

I tried setting withCredentials in the client side, but now I am getting:

```
Credentials flag is true, but Access-Control-Allow-Credentials is not "true".
```

Any idea how to (or if it is possible) to send the cookies with the XHR to the endpoints? Or how to enable `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` on Endpoints?

Comment: So you're using cookies instead of OAuth 2.0 tokens for the request? Are you sure that you have cookies for the appspot domain when you're signed in?

Comment: Yes. No OAuth. When I sign in, the cookie domain is my custom domain. I thought setting the cookie domain to appspot would send the cookie with the requests, but I don't think that's working either. Any idea if that should work?

Comment: That didn't seem to fix it. Cookies are still not being sent with the requests.

Comment: Could you file an issue (so we can contact you privately for your app ID)? On the [issues](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/FilingIssues?tm=3) page choices, I would call this a feature request.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using raw XHRs instead of our client libraries? Our client libraries will create a proxy in an iFrame and the cookies (from the **other** domain) will be passed along correctly. This is still a bad way to go. Why not use OAuth tokens?

Comment: Oh really! I didn't know that. The only reason was I was using AngularJS for the application and found it easier to define my own $resource. I am still new to Angular and there's a lot of stuff I don't understand well, so if the client libraries generated solves this I'll check it out and switch to it.

Comment: The reason I didn't use OAuth is because I am using Facebook Login. I think I should still be able to provide my own OAuth, right? But I still haven't figured that one out. Any pointers that might help?